# VBA Macro if cell contains #N/A then enter text into following column

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have an excel doc which has data copied into Column B. If any of those cells in Column B = "#N/A" I would like my macro to enter a comment in Column C. My loop macro is working until the end when it cannot find anymore "#N/A" values then I get an error "Invalid procedure call or argument". Am I missing something in my macro here?

```
Sub Private()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cel In ws.Range("B2:B5000")
        If CVErr(cel.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Please build missing name"
        End If
    Next cel


End Sub
```

Cheers,

Brandon M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub whateverr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cel In ws.Range("B2:B5000")
        If cel.Text = "#N/A" Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Please build missing name"
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gary's student!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing when you input a range that does not have an error since the only valid input for `CVErr` is an error. Therefore, you should first check to see if an error is actually present before passing your cell into the `CVErr` function

---

```
If IsError(Cel) Then
    If CVErr(cel) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        'Action statements here
    End If
End If
```

---

Per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/cverr-function) for `CVErr`

### Syntax

> CVErr(`errornumber`)
>
> The required `errornumber` argument is any **valid error number**.

Comment: I think you can just do `If cel.Value` since you've already established that it's an error; the key here is the `IsError` check.

Comment: Can confirm that works. No clue if there are any efficiency gains from going straight to the value rather calling the VBA function. Guessing there would be gains over a extremely large data set.  I would just filter for #N/A really to avoid the loop

Comment: ^ I second the filter approach too.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using CVErr on the cell value but directly compare the cell value with CVErr(xlErrNA).

```
If IsError(cel.Value) Then
    If cel.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        ...
```

Unfortunately, VBA does not short-circuit logical and expressions.

Comment: Fixed my answer.